# IOS CGContextDraw Best Way To Create Disappearing Animation

Tags: ios, core-animation, cgcontext

I have a sample screen where a user can draw onto a view with their finger. I want to create a cool animation for the line to disappear. What is the best way to have the end of the line slowly disappear? I want it to get thinner as it is disappearing.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

combine CGContextSetLineWidth and NSTimer , decrease the line with that you want to disappear.